# How to get statistical data of app usage of other applications on IOS using react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I've been trying to see if it's possible to get information about app usage on IOS. For example, how much time a user spends on his/hers Facebook or Safari applications. How could one go about doing this within a react native application? Is it possible to do it with any framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it’s not possible. Apple is very strict about this.**

An app cannot access other apps' sandboxes, for any reason. Everything an app can do is restricted to its own sandbox, and in no way can other sandboxes be accessed.

User security is very important for Apple.

If the app you are trying to get the data about has an SDK that can be integrated in your react native app, and the SDK has APIs to provide information about usage analytics for the user(which I don't think is possible with FB SDK), you could ask the user for authorization via the SDK and show them the usage analytics information. Although, chances of these APIs being in an SDK are slim, this might be the only way.